# How can i name an object after one or more variables

Tags: python

I'm recreating a game (bubble shooter) in PyGame and I need to generate several objects of the same class (in this case the class Bubble), so my idea was to name them after variables, but I'm completely open to different solutions to my problem.

I tried using str() to turn the variables into string and add another "Bubble" this way but that didn't quite work out and I have no idea how to proceed.

```
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, color):
        self.x = pos_x
        self.y = pos_y
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.speed_y = 0
        self.color = color

for n in range(0, 9):
    for m in range(0, 3):
        "b" + str(10*m + n) = Bubble(n*64 + 32, m*64 + 32, random.randint(1,6))
```

As mentioned earlier, my expectation was for it to create several objects in the Bubble class called b1, b2, b3, and so on. But there seems to be an error, and PyCharm says "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" which I don't quite know what it means or how exactly i can fix it.

Comment: Everytime you think about creating variables with dynamic names, think about arrays.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Do you know about lists?

Comment: use dictionary `b[ str(10*m + n) ] =  Bubble(...)`or list `b.append( Bubble(...) )`

Comment: Why not just put them in a list var=[]

Comment: Ive literally seen like 5 duplicate questions in the past 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automatically create a variable using the string as the r.h.s

Comment: It's easy, using `globals()[str_with_name] = value`

Comment: Personally, not really something you would necessarily do when you have other solutions out there more suitable to coding practices (unless completely necessary). However, this is cool method that I did not know about .. adding it to my bag of cool tricks.

Answer (score 0):

**Right way:**
The right (Pythonic) way is to use dictionaries.

```
columns = {}
columns[some_string] = some_value
```

**Unadvised dirty way, but answers your question:** Storing a *string* as a *variable name* in your global namespace can be done simply by (example):

```
some_value = 100
some_string = 'var_name'
globals()[some_string] = some_value
```

The output is then

```
>>> var_name
100
```

On the other hand, if you want to add a variablename locally, you can use `locals()` instead of `globals()`.

I trust you can take over from here!